# Trimming unwanted characters from a large file via batch commands

Tags: batch-file

I have a datafile in the following format

> 012394994SomeunwantedString
>
> 394949585MoreUnwantedString
>
> 348020200
>
> 349585940FurtherUnwantedString

I want to remove the unwanted strings from the file. The problem is, neither the unwanted string not the characters before the string are consistent. The only consistent part is the length of the string that is needed, and after this position I want to trim the rest of the line.

I realize that I can simply extract the characters from the left given that I know the count, but is there a more efficient manner to do this? The file contains over 80,000 lines, out of which only 10-20 will have unwanted characters.

Looking for a set of simple batch commands to get this done as this will need to run on a server.

Comment: Please post the code for which you are hoping for a solution.

Comment: [set](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) and a [for /f](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(
 for /f "delims=" %%a in (infile.name) do (
  set "line=%%a"
  echo(!line:~0,9!
 )
)>"outfile.name"
```

Read each line from the input file, assign to `line` and `echo` the `9` characters starting from index `0`